# Can this juice ferment without added sugar?

Tags: yeast, sugar

If I wanted to make a hooch out of "cranberry juice cocktail", which is composed of "water, cranberry juice, high fructose corn syrup, cranberry juice concentrate, and ascorbic acid, how would I go about that?

Would bakers yeast be able to metabolize this High fructose corn syrup? Would the metabolism of it produce anything undesirable?

Sorry if hooch questions are not allowed.

Comment: Do you have dietary information on it? What is the total sugar content? Pew what volume? For example Coca Cola can I have in front of me has 10.7g of sugar per 100ml. Do you have such data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can. I think Terry Gerry's book (or another, sorry) talks about how cranberry juice and apple cider are often people's first foray into brewing something. It's recommended that you agitate the beeguz out of cranberry juice or cocktail before you pitch yeast (I would use champagne yeast due to its resilience), and give it a shake whenever you pass by it to help the yeast overcome the preservatives.

Answer (score 2):

The listed ingredients are fermentable. As long as there are no preservatives, and the pH isn't crazy low, it will work. Baker's yeast might not give you the best flavor, but I guess you're going to work with what you've got.

Comment: Cranberry juice pH, even in a cocktail of other juices, maybe 'crazy low'.  Define crazy low? pH 2? pH 3?

Comment: Bakers yeast may not tolerate much alcohol either.

Comment: 'Bakers yeast may not tolerate much alcohol...'.  What makes you think that @Escoce ?  In this [forum](https://www.reddit.com/r/Homebrewing/comments/243m4o/used_bakers_yeast_out_of_desperation_what_can_i/), someone got 13% out of baker's yeast.

Comment: Just because is can doesn't mean it always does.

Comment: @brewchez: Yeast will be inhibited below pH 2.9, and cranberry juice should be 2.3-2.5. But Ro Siv is working with a 'cocktail', and pH meter can't reach it from here.